# Image can be downloaded from website but shows "cors" error while on "webview"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

Here is the code that I've used on the react web application for downloading the image. While loading the page and downloading the image from the browser its working fine.
But, I also have rendered the same web application on the react native application on a webview. But the scenario is :
While opening on the browser the image is being downloaded correctly but when on rendering the same on the reactnative webview its showing the cors issue.
Below is the basic function that i've written for downloading the image.

```
const download = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axiosInstance
      .get(item?.doc_filename, {
        responseType: "blob", // Specify that the response should be treated as a binary blob
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        const link = document.createElement("a");

        link.href = url; // Set the href attribute of the link to the created URL
        link.download = "offer_letter.png"; // Set the desired filename for the downloaded image

        document.body.appendChild(link); // Append the link to the document
        link.click();

        URL.revokeObjectURL(url); // Clean up the URL object to release resources
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Below is the image of react native webview inspect.
[image]

Below is the image of browser inspect.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dug up and just adding the "window.postMessage" did the trick.
Hope it helps if anyone stuck similarly.

[image]